# finally block in c#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch-finally

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finally Block Not Running??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193493/finally-block-not-running)

I have a question regarding finally block in c#. 
I wrote a small sample code:

```
public class MyType
{
    public void foo()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Throw NullReferenceException?");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            if (s == "Y")
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            else
                throw new ArgumentException();          
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NullReferenceException was caught!");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finally block");
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyType t = new MyType();
        t.foo();
    }
}
```

As I far as I know, finally block suppose to run deterministicly, whether or not an exception was thrown. 
Now, if the user enters "Y" - NullReferenceException is thrown, execution moves to the catch clock and then to the finally block as I expected.
But if the input is something else - ArgumentException is thrown. There is no suitable catch block to catch this exception, so I thought execution should move the the finally block - but it doesnt. Could someone please explain me why?

thanks everyone :)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193493/finally-block-not-running

Comment: I've tried the code, and it enters the finally block as expected

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ` I thought execution should move the the finally block` - I presume the control is going into the finally in both cases - right?

Comment: Yes, apparently it actually does enter the finally block, and i miss that because of the debugger... :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your debugger is probably catching the ArgumentException so it's waiting for you to "handle" it there before entering the final block. Run your code w/o an attached debugger (including w/o your JIT debugger) and it should hit your finally block.

To disable JIT, go to **Options > Tools > Debugging > Just-In-Time** and uncheck **Managed**

To debug w/o an attached debugger, in Visual Studio go to **Debug > Start Without Debugging** (or **CTRL + F5**)

It would also be helpful to put a Console.ReadLine() at the end of your program to prevent the console from closing after entering your finally block.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyType t = new MyType();
        t.foo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here is the output you should get:

---

> Throw NullReferenceException? N
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ArgumentException: Value does
>   not fall within the ex pected range.
>
> at ConsoleSandbox.MyType.foo() in
>   P:\Documents\Sandbox\Console\Console\Consol
>   e\Program.cs:line 17
>
> at
>   ConsoleSandbox.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in P:\Documents\Sandbox\Console
>   \Console\Console\Program.cs:line 31
>
> **finally block**
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Well, you are right. I didnt think it is related to the debugger because I tried all 4 combinations of the 'Thrown' and 'User-Unhandled' of the CLR Runtime Exceptions in the Exception window. Isnt that related? I mean, if I unchecked those boxes, shouldnt the code run with no interference? Thanks again, for you time.

Comment: You're referring to the [Debug > Exceptions] options; that's different from the Just-In-Time debugger options I mentioned above. The JIT debugger will catch UNHANDLED exceptions whereas the exceptions options you're referring to is Visual Studio's attached debugger.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that Henk Holterman is also correct and surrounding your t.foo() call w/ a try/catch will show that your finally block is indeed called - but that changes your scenario in that your ArgumentException becomes a handled exception and the JIT debugger doesn't make it look like your finally block isn't being called anymore. This is why we should always handle our exceptions =)

Comment: I agree that my code is indeed a bad practice. It was written for learning purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is an artifact of your test program.

If you change your main method:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    try
    {
        MyType t = new MyType();
        t.foo();
    }
    catch
    {
       // write something
    }
 }
```

Then your `foo()` will behave as expected.

Without that toplevel try/catch, your entire program was being aborted.