# Why Dispose is not called even with using-statement?

Tags: c#, dispose

I have this console application (.NET Framework 4.5.2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var result = new Result())
        {
            result.Test();
        }
    }
}

public class Result : IDisposable
{
    public void Test()
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1 / (a - 1);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
    }
}
```

Why `Dispose` method is not called? A breakpoint is not hit in `Dispose` after the `DivideByZero`-exception and there is no output on the console (because the app exits).

Comment: what do you mean? you did not call the Dispose method directly. but you called the Test method instead.

Comment: @jLaw but he wrapped the result in a `using`

Comment: @jLaw the object is in a `using` clause, so one might expect the object to be disposed at the end of the clause

Comment: [Yes it calls dispose](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vyO0l2) (after fixing division by zero exception)

Comment: It's called after throwing the exception. Please check again.

Comment: Why do you think it's not being called?

Comment: @Reniuz it should call dispose even if an exception was thrown

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why not. it's inside a `using` has nothing to do with a try-catch

Comment: @OfirWinegarten: at least you can't set a breakpoint in dispose without the outer try-catch, it will never be hit and the console app will exit without try-catch, so it's understandable why OP thought that dispose is not called. This is a valid question.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten and it is called. The exception mentioned to point that example breaks. And yes I wrote it incorrectly :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see your point. That would probably be a good guess

Comment: @Reniuz: that's not a console app, it's a .NET fiddle sandbox so a different environment

Comment: I have added "File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test.txt", "dispose");" in Dispose method and made a release build. File gets created. Thanks for your comments. It all works.

Comment: @KaMarius: interesting, even with release and  `File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test.txt", "dispose");` the file is not created and written for me. I guess i should not run it from visual studio.

Comment: @TimSchmelter probably you still run that under debugger (starting with F5 in visual studio). Under debugger it will not work even in release mode.

Comment: @Evk: yes, if i run from outside of visual studio (or with ctrl+F5 without debugger) the file is created, so dispose is called.

Comment: @TimothyGroote: The program has an **uncaught exception**. There is no requirement that the end of the using clause is ever reached; programs with **uncaught** exceptions have implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @EricLippert this turned out to be a better question than i thought. thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per MS Docs: [try-finally (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)

> Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed
>   to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the
>   finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is
>   triggered. That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

As you are not catching the `DivideByZero` exception and let it be unhandled, on **your** machine and setup it must be bringing down the application before any other line of code is run and therefore not running the `finally` block.

As @Evk has pointed out in below comment, if I run it without attaching debugger, it unwinds the exceptions correctly and executes the finally block. Learn something new everyday.

As per [Eric Lippert's answer to Finally Block Not Running?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196863/271106)

> Think about how awful that situation is: something unexpected has
>   happened that no one ever wrote code to handle. Is the right thing to
>   do in that situation to run even more code, that was probably also not
>   built to handle this situation? Possibly not. Often the right thing to
>   do here is to not attempt to run the finally blocks because doing so
>   will make a bad situation even worse. You already know the process is
>   going down; put it out of its misery immediately.
>
> In a scenario where an unhandled exception is going to take down the
>   process, anything can happen. It is implementation-defined what
>   happens in this case: whether the error is reported to Windows error
>   reporting, whether a debugger starts up, and so on. The CLR is
>   perfectly within its rights to attempt to run finally blocks, and is
>   also perfectly within its rights to fail fast. In this scenario all
>   bets are off; different implementations can choose to do different
>   things.

Comment: No not always, certain exceptions cause app to completely shut down (e.g. Hardware exceptions). Would of expected this to run the finally block, but I can confirm on my machine it doesn't ever enter the Finally block

Comment: Your wording is misleading, because you say that this finally _never_ gets run, while this is not true (your own quote says that "it depends").

Comment: It also MUCH more likely that OP runs application under debugger in which case VS will terminate process on unhandled exception (will not unwind it). If OP runs without debugger on the same machine and configuration - it will execute finally block.

Comment: @Evk I think you should post that as an answer, as to me I would expect the debugger to run finally block if anything, rather than without it. Thanks for pointing out and can confirm on my machine that your statement is true. Do you know if that is always the case?

Comment: As far as I know - visual studio debugger always "kills" process after unhandled exception, don't know if there are any ways to avoid that. You can emulate the same with `Environment.FailFast` for example. If you do `try { ... some stuff ...; Environment.FailFast("some message");} finally {}` then finally block will not be run even without debugger. Or you can kill process from task manager.

Comment: I think your answer is fine in general case, after all as your Eric Lippert quote says - it's all implementation dependent.